# How to generate Coq files from Frama-C WP plugin

Tags: coq, frama-c

Ive been struggling past few days with the interaction between Coq and Frama-C (and its WP plugin). Ive read throughout most of the guides out there, but they mostly state that this is out of their scope. My current environment consists of:
Frama-C (22.0)
Coq (8.12.0)
Why3 (1.3.3)
All my provers including Coq were found by **why3 config --detect**, but I cant seem to figure it out.
I assumed that Coq IDE would pop out from the Frama-C GUI with the generated proof context, but so far that has not been the case.

Any advice seriously helps, thanks in advance !

Comment: Is the opam package why3-coq installed as well as CoqIde ?

Comment: @Ksass'Peuk Yes, Coq, CoqIDE and why3-coq is all installed.

Comment: Once you have the list of failed proofs in the GUI (WP Goals tab), open the "provers" list in the left panel and select Coq. Then in the WP goals list, select a goal and double clic in the Coq column for this goal. The IDE should pop. If an error happens, a message should be displayed in the "Console" tab.